# Underlying Type of System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Xyz_123

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

A link query returns a object of type:  System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Person_D82ABAE4682B2BBAB103FDB8673CE2...

I need the full type name of the underlying type - here Person object
(MyDomainModel.Person)

How can i get this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use static method GetObjectType of ObjectContext